# Next Badge progress bars are misaligned

Tags: bug, design, badge-progress

I noticed this on the "Select your next badge" screen. This bug doesn't occur on the main profile page.

If you look closely, the green progress bar that fills up the badge progress indicator is misaligned:

[image]

It looks like it's about two pixels up too far. I'm on Chrome 55, Mac OS 10.11.6.

Comment: What's your zoom level on the page?  Also, [does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: No... not at all... *twitch*

Comment: When you recover, check the zoom level and see if it's not at 100%.  If it isn't, reset the zoom and see if you can repro.

Comment: @Will Page zoom is at 0. I forgot to mention, this is on the Next Badge page, not the main profile page. Edited.

Comment: I can repro at the default zoom level.  I took a screen shot and zoomed in on that image and I can see the misalignment.  Win 7 pro 64 bit with the latest chrome.

Comment: Repro on Edge.  Now I'm triggered.

Comment: Also, there are *two versions* of this dialog.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTkeJ.png Weird.

Answer (score 8):

The proximate cause is the following style definition:

```
.badges-card .progress-bar .percent, .all-badge-progress .progress-bar .percent, .badges-card .progress-bar-large .percent, .all-badge-progress .progress-bar-large .percent
{
   position: relative;
   top:      -1px;
   left:     -1px;
   height:   26px;
}
```

In particular, setting the `top` and `left` to an offset of -1 pixels for the `progress-bar` class. If you remove these, the problem is solved, without any other obvious ill effects.

I'm not sure what the rationale is for these curious offsets—maybe fixing similar a UI bug on a *different* browser?

Comment: Maybe it’s supposed to be some 3D effect.

Comment: @Xufox Yeah, it's a *feature*.